# How to edit WooCommerce 'added to basket' banner

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I would like to edit this part of my website, which is the banner that pops up on a product page when you add that product to the basket:

[image: WooCommerce banner]

I have looked through every file in the WooCommerce folder for the text string 'has been added to your basket', figuring this is where I would make required changes. However I can't find the string anywhere, and so am at a loss of how to edit this section.

Answer (score 1):

use `wc_add_to_cart_message_html` filter It's in `wc_add_to_cart_message` function in `wc-cart-functions.php` .

Example:

```
add_filter('wc_add_to_cart_message_html', function( $old_message, $products ) {
    $new_message = '<span> new message </span>';
    return $new_message;
}, 100, 2 );
```

Comment: Lovely, thank you. I've managed to get it to display 'new message' and nothing else. Are you able to advise on how to get a custom message alongside the default message? I will keep tinkering.

Comment: I don't get what you specifically want to do, but the function has everything 
I think you will need wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) and you can apply the same the function does but with your custom way

Comment: I found another solution to my problem in the end, but your comment was very helpful in figuring out where to start looking. Thanks.